# Robot FW: Builtin library : Should Not Be Equal 0b1011 11 : Passes but its should fail, why?

Tags: robotframework, built-in

Consider the following usage of "Should Not Be Equal" keyword:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Use "Should Not Be Equal"
     Should Not Be Equal 0b1011    11   # Should fail, but passes. Why?
     Should Not Be Equal     0b1011    0xB   # Should fail, but passes. Why?
```

**The goal** is to provide a negative failing test case by providing 0b1011 (i.e. 11 in base 10)
and 11 (in base 10). Since 11 == 11 is True (in base 10), this test case should fail.

**The actual result** is that the test case passes, why?

Comment: I have to ask it - why are you testing fundamental aspects of the Robot Framework itself? The last questions you have posted on SO are for checking its internal/builtin keywords themselves.

Comment: Todor Minakov, I am writing test cases utilizing the builtin library to better understand the buildin library itself. Simply by reading the builtin library spec, i cannot learn. As i develop test cases, there comes questions and i turn StackOverflow for help.

Comment: OK, understood :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by default, all arguments to keywords are passed as strings. So this call:

```
Should Not Be Equal    0b1011    11
```

, is similar to python's

```
"0b1011" != "11"
```

, which evaluates to True.

If you want to check the integers/numerical values, this is the way:

```
Should Not Be Equal    ${0b1011}    ${11}   # will fail, they are equal.
```